# Why is my Strongarm feature immediately overridden?

Tags: 7, features, strongarm

I am using features to save a content type.  Here are the fields that my new feature contains:

```
body  field_product_site_id  field_product_repair_price  field_product_manufacturer  field_product_description  field_product_terms  field_product_url  field_product_model  field_assigned_to  field_role_designater

node-product-body  node-product-field_product_description  node-product-field_product_manufacturer  node-product-field_product_model  node-product-field_product_repair_price  node-product-field_product_site_id  node-product-field_product_terms  node-product-field_product_url  node-user_role_marker-field_assigned_to  node-user_role_marker-field_role_designater
```

I decided to add the Strongarm module to capture additional fields (and hopefully save the field order/weights of my content types.)  The strongarm module added a few new variables to the list:

```
 field_bundle_settings_node__product  menu_options_product  menu_parent_product  node_options_product  node_preview_product  node_submitted_product
```

After recreating the feature, I discovered that it had become overridden.  As I understand it, features are only overridden if the data stored within it is difference that the data stored in the database.  How can this feature be overridden as soon as it is created?

Edit =========================================

The feature now seems to be in the Default state.  All I did was install the diff module.  Could this have been a cache issue?

Comment: Is the feature exporting timestamps or user IDs? A feature showing as overridden can be caused by something as simple as that.

Comment: I have no idea at this point, the feature is suddenly in default.

Comment: I have found that this issue is often cleared up by setting the value manually by ```variable_set(some_variable, value)```

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell why it's telling you something is changed, but you can use Diff module to see what changed. [Diff module](https://drupal.org/project/diff)